# window.print() does not work in IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, internet-explorer, printing-web-page

I have an angular js app and for a print functionality I am opening an html page using the window.open method.

```
 public openNewWindow(html: string, title: string) {
    var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'scrollbars=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,titlebar=no, height=500, weidth=900');
    popupWin.window.focus();
    popupWin.document.write(html);
    popupWin.document.title = title;
};
```

I have a button on the html page to Print. I use the onclick event to call print.

```
 <button class="print-btn" onclick="window.print();" id="view_print"> Print</button>
```

This code perfectly works in Chrome, but not in IE 11. If I change the default from Edge to IE 10 the print seem to be working and opening the print dialog window. It is definitely slower than the Chrome.

I have tried adding the emulation as below (for IE 10 and 8 etc) but it still does not work.

am I missing anything here? I find a lot of articles but I have not been able to fix it.

Comment: What does not work?

Comment: the print dialog window that should come to select printer does not appear. It behaves OK with chrome.

Comment: If you add `type="button"` to the button, does it make a difference

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: And there is no error in the console and no item with the id "print" on the page?

Comment: no nothing as such

Answer (score 1):

Scripted popup windows with size and position parameters are subject to Popup blocker and IE Security zone restrictions. try

window.open('', '_blank');

Use the File>Properties menu to determine which IE Security zone a web page/domain maps to.

See any Wikipedia article side bar for a template method of formatting the current web page in a printer friendly format using media queries.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing this also, but with the following information:

- under Chrome: address at bottom of page is (the correct) `http://server/path/file.php?querystring`
- under IE11: address at bottom of page is `http://server/path/{8 digit dynamic alphanumeric string}.htm`

The onscreen rendering is correct, but the printed result is a 404 error.

The current work around is to use Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you have new system, and after trying everything this is not working out,

Try setting Printer First.

Set Default Printer and your IE should start responding to

```
"Ctrl" + "P"
```

or

```
window.print()
```